# Should this question about Google Chrome be migrated to Super User from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

It is [suggested in a comment in a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636612/prevent-google-chrome-unloading-or-discarding-tabs#comment133442708_75636612) that the question [*Prevent Google Chrome unloading or discarding tabs?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636612/prevent-google-chrome-unloading-or-discarding-tabs) should be migrated to superuser.

I am not sure if that's correct, hence seeking feedback here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I am not sure if that's correct.

It would be a fine question on SuperUser. However moderators cannot migrate from another site. You would have to flag your question and ask the StackOverflow moderators to migrate it.

I don't really use Chrome - it is possible that your question is a duplicate of
[How can I get Chrome to stop killing my tabs in the background?](https://superuser.com/questions/1353931/how-can-i-get-chrome-to-stop-killing-my-tabs-in-the-background/1353940#1353940)

Comment: I suspect the reason I never found that question in my searches is because google seems to change the terminology every few years. Also chrome's search inside settings is awful, it really doesn't point users to the setting that would help them, but rather seems to do a literal `grep` on the search term. Anyway, a recent answer on the question you linked to solves all my problems, and without any Chrome Addons. Thanks a lot for this.